# What is the difference between the two transaction headers on the Bitcoin Liquid sidechain network?

Tags: block-header, blockstream, liquid

You can see transactions for this asset
https://blockstream.info/liquid/address/H4UWQS836njW4QJ6WfkGAPjaYtK2twLnZE

For the second transaction, it has a header of

- 802dc4c4a08fcf4f50e4320bdb5eb596afc01c95dd0ff6afb83304aeb989be15 (2020-01-07 11:21:58 UTC)

Underneath the transaction, is a another header of

- 81efc96bea93fcb5992831d8311dec63a0b1d17072ec2e6f1263901b1bd26000 (2019-10-31 19:05:58 UTC)

What is the difference between these two? why does one transaction have two headers?

Comment: Which headers and transaction have you mentioned in the last question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tx: [802dc4c4a08fcf4f50e4320bdb5eb596afc01c95dd0ff6afb83304aeb989be15](https://mempool.space/liquid/tx/802dc4c4a08fcf4f50e4320bdb5eb596afc01c95dd0ff6afb83304aeb989be15)

Inputs:

```
38V6gLL6kVCWhfXPo4t5x1gMfg5BKe3Rv
H18z1ifzs184pzwTABag5gv47AAxZSi1qg
```

Outputs:

```
H38V6gLL6kVCWhfXPo4t5x1gMfg5BKe3Rv
H4UWQS836njW4QJ6WfkGAPjaYtK2twLnZE
GnHogGZpDCwmskKFJoVhuvgUg6gKhWQjy6
```

Tx: [81efc96bea93fcb5992831d8311dec63a0b1d17072ec2e6f1263901b1bd26000](https://mempool.space/liquid/tx/81efc96bea93fcb5992831d8311dec63a0b1d17072ec2e6f1263901b1bd26000)

Inputs:

```
Gm5rw7zmqdMV1ajbT6zTEEDJhSHK1Ymdfq
H38V6gLL6kVCWhfXPo4t5x1gMfg5BKe3Rv
```

Outputs:

```
H38V6gLL6kVCWhfXPo4t5x1gMfg5BKe3Rv
H4UWQS836njW4QJ6WfkGAPjaYtK2twLnZE
GisytKX4AhQ8B1aH4p9fHsNuRbpzSr1VdF
```

Comment: Thanks Prayank. The explorer you used is much easier to follow!